# Internal server error from ArcGIS for Android sync?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-android

I am trying to use server based offline maps to do all my edits offline and sync them to the server online. I am able to do all my edits usccessfully. However, when I am doing sync using the geodatabaseSyncTask.syncGeodatabase() call, everytime I see, "Internal Server Error".
Can somebody let me know if this is an issue at my end or the service end?

```
geodatabaseSyncTask.syncGeodatabase(syncParams, localGdb, statusCallback, syncResponseCallback);
```